# In python elif statement is an invalid syntax in a while statement

Tags: python, python-3.3

```
while True :

    print ("Do you like ice cream?")
    Icecream = input ()
    if Icecream == ('yes' or 'y' or 'ye'):
        print ("Damn right!")
    break;

    elif Icecream == ('no' or 'nah' or 'n' or 'No' or 'Nah' or 'N' or 'Nope' or 'nope'):
        print ("Why not??")
        break;

    else :
        print ('Command not recognised, please use yes or no')
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
When I run it through it says the Elif is an invalid syntax, How do i fix it?

Comment: Make sure your code snippet is indented correctly (looks the same as your actual code) - indentation matters a lot in Python.

Comment: break; resets the indentation, and ends the if block.

Comment: @Kursion not everyone is an American, Robbie is obviously using 'ye' for yes, so there's a tipoff for you, too.

Comment: Your comparisons aren't doing what you think they do. You really want `if Icecream in ('yes', 'y', 'ye'):` Otherwise `('yes' or 'y' or 'ye')` gets evaluated as a boolean statement, which will turn it into just `'yes'`. So you end up really doing `if Icecream == 'yes':`. Same issue with the second if block.

Comment: @Kursion it is, because you're wrong - in England and other places, they spell things differently. "Correcting" `colour` to `color` or `recognise` to `regonize` or `tyre` to `tire` is not a correction at all, just you choosing to apply American standards to other peoples' spelling. Do you ever wonder why sometimes software makes you click the little American flag vs, say, the British flag when you choose a language? This is why.

Comment: ok my bad, removed my comments.... wooouh what an aggression here ;) I'm french :D

Answer (score 0):

The break statement under print ("Damn right") is not indented, so the if is then "finished" and the elif does not belong to any if.

Also, no need for a ; after break.

Answer (score -1):

You need to tab the break for the if part. It isn't indented correctly.  Under `print ("Damn right!")` you need to properly add a tab or spaces.

```
while True :

print ("Do you like ice cream?")
Icecream = input ()
if Icecream == ('yes' or 'y' or 'ye'):
    print ("Damn right!")
    break;

elif Icecream == ('no' or 'nah' or 'n' or 'No' or 'Nah' or 'N' or 'Nope' or 'nope'):
    print ("Why not??")
    break;

else :
    print ('Command not recognised, please use yes or no')
```